# How to store/access a local sql database on Android via Java

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I am currently developing an Android app in Eclipse with Java.  I need to store some data.  I could use XML, or CSV, but I would prefer to have some sort of database locally that I can query to with sql.  If there is some type of editing interface would also be good.

A good example would be Microsoft Access, but obviously that would not work on Android.  You know, just somewhere simple where i can store data locally.  Nothing complicated.  Ease-of-development would be very useful.

Is there anything like that in the Android world?

Comment: Android uses SQLite for the database. For the starter, you can read [the official doc regarding the SQLite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

Answer (score 0):

Data in android are usually stored in SQLite database. Personally I use [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) - it's well documented and works like a charm...